# How can I give file extentions list using FileDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filedialog

I can give extentions for file using JFileChooser.
Example:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
```

But I can understand how to do this same thing Using FileDialog .
My question is how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

void   setFilenameFilter(FilenameFilter filter) 
              Sets the filename filter for this file dialog window to the specified filter.

Comment: How can I initilize the the Filenamefilter object filter with file extentions list?

Comment: fd.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter(){
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
      return (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".gif"));
    }
 });

Comment: But I still can not display the file extentions list in files of type
box .
how can I display this list?

Comment: check this URL http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-implement-java-filefilter-list-files-directory